# Unable to get distinct records in SQL with distinct command

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, distinct

I used the following query to get distinct records from a table

```
 SELECT distinct UFT
      ,ID
      ,NUM
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), UFT, 120) AS FTC
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), TIMESTAMP, 120) as TIMESTAMP
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), UIT, 120) AS UIT
      ,RANGE
      ,FORCE/1000/2 as FORCE
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), LFT, 120) as LFT
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), LIT, 120) as LIT
  FROM TABLE1
  where ID = 2 
  AND NUM = '144'
  AND UFT > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    and UFT <= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000'
  order by FTC, UIT  desc
```

And the output is

```
UFT ID  NUM FTC TIMESTAMP   UIT RANGE   FORCE   LFT LIT
2014-08-22 16:00:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 16:00:00 2014-08-22 14:30:31 2014-08-22 11:40:54 5.00    0.792000000 2014-08-22 16:00:00 2014-08-22 12:40:54
2014-08-22 16:30:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 16:30:00 2014-08-22 15:30:30 2014-08-22 12:40:48 5.00    0.836000000 2014-08-22 16:30:00 2014-08-22 13:40:48
2014-08-22 17:00:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 17:00:00 2014-08-22 15:30:30 2014-08-22 12:40:48 5.10    0.880000000 2014-08-22 17:00:00 2014-08-22 13:40:48
2014-08-22 17:30:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 17:30:00 2014-08-22 16:30:30 2014-08-22 13:40:24 5.20    0.932000000 2014-08-22 17:30:00 2014-08-22 14:40:24
2014-08-22 18:00:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 18:00:00 2014-08-22 16:30:30 2014-08-22 13:40:24 5.30    0.984000000 2014-08-22 18:00:00 2014-08-22 14:40:24
2014-08-22 21:30:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 21:30:00 2014-08-22 20:30:30 2014-08-22 17:40:52 6.40    1.656000000 2014-08-22 21:30:00 2014-08-22 18:40:52
2014-08-22 21:30:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 21:30:00 2014-08-22 17:30:30 2014-08-22 17:07:40 6.60    1.860000000 2014-08-22 21:30:00 2014-08-22 18:07:40
2014-08-22 22:00:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 22:00:00 2014-08-22 20:30:30 2014-08-22 17:40:52 6.40    1.704000000 2014-08-22 22:00:00 2014-08-22 18:40:52
2014-08-22 22:00:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 22:00:00 2014-08-22 17:30:30 2014-08-22 17:07:40 6.70    1.904000000 2014-08-22 22:00:00 2014-08-22 18:07:40
2014-08-22 22:30:00.000 2   144 2014-08-22 22:30:00 2014-08-22 21:30:28 2014-08-22 18:40:49 6.50    1.764000000 2014-08-22 22:30:00 2014-08-22 19:40:49
```

Inspite of using distinct on UFT column I still find multiple records in the output. What could be the reason for this and is there a way to improve the query

Comment: The distinct keyword applies to all columns in the select statement, not just the first column after the distinct.  Could you format the results more clearly and put an example of the results you are looking for?

Comment: impossible to read. However, `distinct` works on an entire set, no just a column.

Comment: If it works on the entire set why is that UFT coulmn is not distinct. I am not sure I understand. The result I want is distinct entries in UFT coulmn and other multiple entry rows to be omitted. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: @RVRLibra It's because the entire row is not a duplicate.  It looks at every column.  If you look at rows 6 and 7 in your results, not all the values in all columns are the same.  Look at the 5th column, TIMESTAMPS, the values in the 6th and 7th rows are not the same.  So in that example, which row would you want displayed, 6 or 7?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10733854/1048425), although I am not quite convinced the linked question is general enough for this to be considered a duplicate. Since a single vote from me would close the question I will leave this judgement to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained for others `distinct` operates on entire rows and not individual columns.

I have added a new column that would let you eliminate the rows that come after the first appearance of a `UFT` value in the sorting. I had to guess that you want to keep the rows with the earlier `timestamp` value and that you also wanted to partition on `FTC`: change as appropriate in the `row_number` expression.

```
with data as (
    SELECT
         UFT
        ,row_number() over (partition by FTC, UFT order by TIMESTAMP) as rn
        ,ID
        ,NUM
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), UFT, 120) AS FTC
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), TIMESTAMP, 120) as TIMESTAMP
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), UIT, 120) AS UIT
        ,RANGE
        ,FORCE/1000/2 as FORCE
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), LFT, 120) as LFT
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), LIT, 120) as LIT
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE
            ID = 2 
        AND NUM = '144'
        AND UFT >  '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
        AND UFT <= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000'
)
select * from data where rn = 1
ORDER BY
    FTC, UIT DESC
```

Your query shows `UIT` in descending order and I do not see that matching the output you've provided. Not sure if that's significant.